# Insertar datos en tabla pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo las siguientes tablas

```
**estudiante**
- id
- nombre


**grupo**
-id
-nombre


**estudiante_grupo**
-id
-grupoId
-estudianteId
```

entonces, yo quiero registrar en la tabla **grupo**, y luego registrar en **estudiante_grupo** con las id's del estudiante como arreglo. y la ultima id generada de la tabla **grupo**. Puedo hacerlo mediante "query builders" pero me gustaria hacerlo y ahorrar codigo con eloquent.
otra pregunta, seria necesario crear un modelo para la tabla detalle **estudiante_grupo**

**Lo que tengo hecho(y funcionando):**

```
$lastId = DB::table("grupo") -> insertGetId(
[
   "nombre" => $request -> nombre
]);

foreach($request -> estudiantesIds as $estId) {
   DB::table("estudiante_grupo") -> insert([
      "grupoId" => $lastId,
      "estudianteId" => $estId
   ])
}
```

El arreglo **$request -> estudiantesIds** son valores numericos:

```
[1,2... ,n]
```

Comment: En esta tabla: `estudiante_grupo` cual de las llave foráneas identifica al estudiante?

Comment: perdon, no me fije. pretendia usar otro ejemplo y cambie de opinion al ultimo. seria cursoId por estudianteId

Comment: Llevas algo al momento? alguna consulta recuerda que eso mejora la recepción de tu duda y evitaría su cierre

Comment: Por ejemplo agrega lo que lleves hecho con query builder eso demuestra algo de intento :)

Comment: ya esta, es que stackoverflow no me permitia subir mas codigo que texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu escenario es una relación **Muchos a muchos**

**Configuración de los modelos**

Tus modelos:

- Deben incluir el nombre de la llave foránea del modelo que hace la relación y la llave foránea del modelo con el que se va a relacionar pues el nombre de dichas columnas no sigue las convenciones de nombres de laravel.

Donde originalmente deberían ser así:

- **`estudiante_id`**
- **`grupo_id`**
- Además como las tablas relacionadas con tus modelos están en singular tampoco siguen la convención de nombres por lo tanto debes agregar dicho valor en una propiedad

Modelo Estudiante

```
class Estudiante extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'estudiante';
    public function grupos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Grupo::class, 'estudiante_grupo', 'estudianteId', 'grupoId');
    }
}
```

Modelo Grupo

```
class Grupo extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'grupo';
    public function estudiantes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Estudiante::class, 'estudiante_grupo', 'grupoId', 'estudianteId');
    }
}
```

Los argumentos que vas a pasar al método desde la segunda hasta la cuarta posición se agregarán en función de si sigues o no las convenciones de Laravel y son:

- Tabla pivot (tu tabla intermedia)
- Llave foránea que identifica al modelo que hace la relación
- Llave foránea que identifica al modelo con el cual se hará la relación

**Alta de registros para ambos modelos**

En este punto ya debiste haber hecho el alta tanto del usuario como del grupo con una sintaxis similar a esta:

```
$nuevoEstudiante = Estudiante::create($request->all());
```

Y

```
$nuevoGrupo = Grupo::create($request->all());
```

Lo anterior es la sintaxis mas corta y funcional posible con la que vas a dar de alta un nuevo registro para cada uno de los modelos; hacer uso de `$request->all()` es tomar todos los valores que manda el usuario y registrarlos donde corresponda.

Importante recordar que para poder usar el método `create` deberás indicar en la propiedad [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) que valores permitirás asignamiento masivo.

**Obtener ids y registro de los mismos en la tabla pivot**

Ahora necesitamos encontrar el id del usuario y el id del grupo al que será adjuntado su registro.

```
$userId  = User::findOrFail($alumnoInscrito);

$grupoId = Grupo::findOrFail($grupoSeleccionado);
```

Ahora le haremos un `attach` del id gr

```
$userId->grupos()->attach($grupoId);
```

Lo anterior deberá estar agregando a tu tabla el id del estudiante y el id del grupo

**REFERENCIAS**

- [método **`attach`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)
- [Relación muchos a muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 2):

En esta respuesta, he supuesto varias cosas, que la relacion es muchos a muchos y que en la tabla intermedia cursoId te has equivocado y seria estudianteId.

Suponiendo que te has creado los modelos Grupo y Estudiante para para las tablas grupos y estudiantes respectivamente.

Para insertar un array de ids de estudiante que tu recibes por parametro al grupo recien creado sería así:

```
//Modelo Estudiante
class Estudiante extends Model 
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'nombre',
        ]

        public function grupos(): BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Grupo', 'estudiante_grupo');
        }
    }

// Moduelo Grupo
class Grupo extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
    ]

    public function estudiantes(): BelongsToMany
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Estudiante', 'estudiante_grupo');
    }
}

//Solución

// Registrar grupo
$datosGrupo = [
    'nombre' => 'el nombre que sea',
];

$grupoCreado = Group::create($datosGrupo);

$grupoCreado->estudiantes()->sync($estudiandsIds);
```

Comment: No veo donde está declarada está variable $estudiandsIds

Comment: No pretenderas que le haga todo. Tampoco he puesto <?php ni el controlador ni nada... Esa variable la tiene el, mira su pregunta

Comment: de donde saldria el  BelongsToMany despues de la funcion grupos() y estudiantes().

Comment: BelongstoMany significa una relacion muchos a muchos, implica una tabla intermedia que se declara como segundo parametro del metodo

Comment: tendras alguna documentacion para aprender mas de eso? es la primera vez que veo una funcion asi. 
(: BelongsToMany) acaso es para especificar el valor de retorno de dicha funcion?

Comment: @Raphael solo es una característica de PHP añadida en versiones recientes aquí puedes leer más https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php llamada declaración de tipo de devolución

Comment: Correcto, a partir de php 7.0 las funciones puedes "tiparlas", osea se, especificar el tipo de valor de retorno @Raphael

Answer (score 1):

Con `Eloquent` puedes usar los métodos:

- `sync: refresca relacion en tabla Pivote`
- `attach: agrega relacion a la tabla pivote`

Pero necesitas definir las relacion `M <-> M` en los respectivos modelos de `Grupo` y `Estudiante`

```
class Estudiante extends Model{
    protected $table='estudiante';//nombre de la tabla DB
    // Con tal de mostrar el ejemplo, no será necesaria Fillable, 

    public function grupos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modelo\Grupo', 'estudiante_grupo', 'id', 'grupoId'); //en caso de error puedes cambiar el orden de los últimos
    }
}

class Grupo extends Model{
    protected $table='grupo';//nombre de la tabla DB
    // Con tal de mostrar el ejemplo, no será necesaria Fillable, 

    public function estudiantes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modelo\Estudiante', 'estudiante_grupo', 'id', 'estudianteId'); //en caso de error puedes cambiar el orden de los últimos
    }
}
```

**Métodos Guardar y Actualizar**

Antes de usar `attach` debemos guardar el `Grupo` para que pueda tomar el `id` de este, puedes usar normal el `sync` si deseas, y con este método te olvidas del `for` y `dettach`, ya que la tabla `pivote`, no tiene datos relevante, y no se necesita ni crear `Modelo`

```
function updategrupo(Request $req){
    $lista = json_decode($req->estudiantesIds ,true); // [1,2,3,4 ...] o puede ser directo si ya es una lista
    $gr=new Grupo();
    $gr->nombre = "nombre";
    $gr->save();
    $gr->estudiantes()->attach($lista);
}
function updategrupo(Request $req, $i){
    $lista = json_decode($req->estudiantesIds ,true); // [1,2,3,4 ...] o puede ser directo si ya es una lista
    $gr=Grupo::find($i);
    $gr->estudiantes()->sync($lista);
}
```